# Space group issue with XYZ, VASP formats in VESTA

Tags: atomic-simulation-environment, vesta, materials-design

I am facing an issue while converting `.cif`/`.vesta` files into `.xyz` and `.vasp` format in which the original space group of the unit cell/super cell crystal automatically gets converted to the $P1$ space group. After converting to `.xyz`, when I try to redefine space group through `edit --> edit data --> unit cell`, the structure gets completely ruined.

How can I redefine space group after converting to `.xyz` without ruining the crystal structure? If this is not possible, can I label atoms without converting from `.vesta` to `.xyz format? Vesta does                                                                                          not index/label atoms that are transformed from unit cell to supercell/bulk structure.

### Vesta file

[image: .vesta file with space group and lattice parameter]

### xyz, incorrect lattice parameters

[image: .xyz file with ruined space group and lattice parameters]

Comment: By default importing file will be P1 structure. You can export to POSCAR and check symmetry using vaspkit/spglib/ASE. It will be same space group as import file

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!! @pranavkumar why not write a full answer? [Comments are temporary, "there's no version history and when they're deleted they cannot be brought back"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: When you convert to XYZ, all the crystal/symmetry information is lost.

Comment: @Camps do you think you can write an answer? user14295847, have you figured this out now? Please give us an update!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned (OP hasn't returned since shortly after posting). It can be reopened if OP returns and expresses renewed interest.